# Fabric8 unable to start on windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubectl, minikube, fabric8

I'm trying to run gofabric8 start on windows 10 i've the `minikube` and `kubectl` running perfectly but when I tried to run gofabric8 start it is giving me an error like `Cannot connect to API server` i tried setting no_proxy and everything but it is still giving me this error. please help me !!!

Comment: it looks like you truncated the error message; what was the _rest_ of the error? Separately, have you run [gofabric8 validate](http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gofabric8.html#validating-your-cluster) to see what it says?

Comment: thankx man it worked, problem was in my kube path thank you.